# JS: Changing the value of an instance with a global function

Tags: javascript, collision

I'm working on a collision function for an experiment, in my main code I have a class called Platform and I'm trying to change it's X/Y values with an outside function. I know I can put the function inside the class itself, but I want to be able to reuse it on different classes.

Example:

```
function changeX(x) {
    x += 20;
  return x;
}

class Box {
    constructor(posX) {
    this.posX = posX;
  };

  change() {
    changeX(this.posX);
  }
};

const box1 = new Box(20);
var box2 = new Box(40);

console.log("Pre Function Call:");
console.log("Box 1: " + box1.posX);
console.log("Box 2: " + box2.posX);

changeX(box1.posX);
box2.change();

console.log("");
console.log("Post Function Call:")
console.log("Box 1: " + box1.posX);
console.log("Box 2: " + box2.posX);
```

I've searched for ways to do this but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeX() {
    this.posX += 20;
}

class Box {
    constructor(posX) {
        this.posX = posX;
    }
};

Box.prototype.change = changeX;



const box1 = new Box(20);
var box2 = new Box(40);

console.log("Pre Function Call:");
console.log("Box 1: " + box1.posX);
console.log("Box 2: " + box2.posX);
changeX.apply(box1);
box2.change();

console.log("");
console.log("Post Function Call:")
console.log("Box 1: " + box1.posX);
console.log("Box 2: " + box2.posX);
```

set Class's prototype or use apply function

If class's attribute depends on class, you can use factory function

```
function changeX(attr) {
    return (function (){
        this[attr] += 20;
    }).bind(this)
}
Box.prototype.change = changeX('posX');
```